# How do I make dependencies (NumPy etc) available to my custom module/function?

Tags: python-3.x, python-import, python-module

As a learning exercise I've written my own tokenization and bag-of-words and tfidf vectorizing functions. They run fine when defined within a Jupyter Notebook. In order to tidy things up, I have saved these functions and some sub-functions to .py files that can be imported from within a simple modules within ./src/features/ within my project directory.

An example of one of these is:

```
# extract_tokens.py
def extract_tokens(text,ngrams,stem):

    """This function takes selftext from a Reddit post, strips URLs, newline formatting strings,
    and non alphabetic characters, removes stopwords, and returns a lower case list of words """

    import re
    from nltk.corpus import stopwords as sw
    from nltk.stem.snowball import SnowballStemmer

    text=text.lower()

    ...

    # Remove stopwords (from nltk)
    s_words=sw.words('english')
    if stem==1:
        Stemmer=SnowballStemmer("english")
```

I have run into an issue where these functions when loaded cannot 'see' other imported modules like re or nltk, and so have rather crudely imported the dependencies within the function. Unfortunately, the script above is called individually on each document in my corpus and I think this is really slowing it down.

My functions are defined in groups in /src/foo/custom.py - is there some lines I could add at the top of that file that would cause the dependencies to be loaded whenever that module or any individual function within it is called?

The structure of the custom.py files is:

```
# extract_tokens.py
def extract_tokens(text,ngrams,stem):

    """This function takes selftext from a Reddit post, strips URLs, newline formatting strings,
    and non alphabetic characters, removes stopwords, and returns a lower case list of words """

    import re
    from nltk.corpus import stopwords as sw
    from nltk.stem.snowball import SnowballStemmer

    ...

    return tokens

# get_tokens.py
def get_tokens(texts,ngrams,stem):

    """extracts unique relevant word tokens from a list of texts using extract_tokens()"""

    ...

    return tokens


# gen_bow_vecs.py
def gen_bow_vecs(texts,ngrams=1,stem=0,**vocab):

    """Create bag-of-words vector representations from a Series of strings"""
    from nltk.corpus import stopwords 
    import numpy as np
    from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix

    ...

    return bvecs
```

etc